# how annotation @Repository in java spring work?

Tags: java, spring

I have a code like this:

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface EquipmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Equipment, Integer>{

Equipment findById(int id);
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class EquipmentServiceImpl implements EquipmentService {

@Autowired
EquipmentRepository equipmentRepository;

@Override
public Equipment findById(int id) {
    return equipmentRepository.findById(id);
   }
}
```

I wonder that why i can call a method of 'interface  EquipmentRepository'. EquipmentRepository is a interface, Right ?

Comment: You mean how does spring data JPA work? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15571608/217324. The Repository annotation is marking this as a component and providing exception translation, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/12204035/217324

Comment: It have a bit difference here. EquipmentRepository is a interface. So, why I can call method of EquipmentRepository. Where is Class that implement EquipmentRepository.

Comment: In this case the `@Repository` is useless. As it is Spring Data JPA that detects extends of `Repository` (the interface not the annotation) to dynamically create JPA implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Repository is responsible for importing the DAO's into the DI container and also it makes the unchecked exceptions into Spring `DataAccessException`. The Spring Repository annotation is meta annotated with the @Component annotation so that the repository classes will be taken up for component scanning.

> Teams implementing traditional Java EE patterns such as "Data Access
>   Object" may also apply this stereotype to DAO classes, though care
>   should be taken to understand the distinction between Data Access
>   Object and DDD-style repositories before doing so. This annotation is
>   a general-purpose stereotype and individual teams may narrow their
>   semantics and use as appropriate.
>
> A class thus annotated is eligible for Spring `DataAccessException`
>   translation when used in conjunction with a
>   `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor`. The annotated class is
>   also clarified as to its role in the overall application architecture
>   for the purpose of tooling, aspects, etc.
>
> Source: [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html)

but in your case you are also extending the `JpaRepository` of Spring Data JPA. Spring Data automatically provides implementations of common CRUD operations. The `JpaRepository` extends the interface `CrudRepository` which has the methods declared for all basic crud operations.

```
public interface EquipmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> { … }
```

Defining this interface serves two purposes:

- First, by extending [`JpaRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) we get a bunch of generic CRUD
  methods into our type that allows saving Equipments, deleting them and
  so on.
- Second, this will allow the Spring Data JPA repository infrastructure
  to scan the classpath for this interface and create a Spring bean for
  it.

The `@EnableJpaRepositories` scans all packages below `com.acme.repositories` for interfaces extending `JpaRepository` and creates a Spring bean for it that is backed by an implementation of `SimpleJpaRepository` (spring data provides default imlpementations of CRUD repository through this class).

So that is why even when you haven't defined the method , you are able to do crud operations through this setup.

Refer : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.repositories