# Spring Java Config DI defining and a ("concrete interface") of JpaRepository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the below code.

Note that I have an interface MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract.

And I have a "concrete interface" MySuperCoolEntityJpaRepository that implements my above MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract interface and JpaRepository.

All of that works fine with @ComponentScan.

I am changing my code to "java config", aka a centralized location where I can code up my DI definitions.  (Also known as CompositionRoot in some circles).

The issue is when I try to "code up" the concrete for the interface.  (Skip down to later in this question.

```
package com.me.domain.jpaentities;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity(name = "MySuperCoolEntityTableName")
public class MySuperCoolEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CoolSurrogateKeyColumn")
    private String coolSurrogateKey;

    @Column(name = "CoolMagicValueColumn")
    private String coolMagicValue;


    public String getCoolSurrogateKey() {
        return this.coolSurrogateKey;
    }

    public void setCoolSurrogateKey(String coolSurrogateKey) {
        this.coolSurrogateKey = coolSurrogateKey;
    }

    public String getCoolMagicValue() {
        return this.coolMagicValue;
    }

    public void setCoolMagicValue(String coolMagicValue) {
        this.coolMagicValue = coolMagicValue;
    }

}
```

===============

```
package com.me.dal.repositories.interfaces;

import com.me.domain.jpaentities.MySuperCoolEntity;
import java.util.Collection;

public interface MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract {

    Collection<MySuperCoolEntity> findByCoolMagicValue(String coolMagicValue);

}
```

=========================

```
package com.me.dal.repositories;

import com.me.dal.repositories.interfaces.MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract;
import com.me.domain.jpaentities.MySuperCoolEntity;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Collection;

@Repository
public interface MySuperCoolEntityJpaRepository extends MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract, JpaRepository<MySuperCoolEntity,String> {

    Collection<MySuperCoolEntity> findByCoolMagicValue(String coolMagicValue);

}
```

Now this issue.

```
package com.me.myapplication.configuration;

import com.me.dal.repositories.MySuperCoolEntityJpaRepository;
import com.me.dal.repositories.interfaces.MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyCompositionRoot {


    @Bean
    public MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract getAMySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract()
    {
        return new MySuperCoolEntityJpaRepository();  /* << issue is here, this is an abstract class, aka, an interface with some methods defined */
    }

}
```

Using the super cool JpaRepository "concrete interface" aka "really an abstract class but called an interface" aka "Interface Default Methods" ( see https://dzone.com/articles/interface-default-methods-java ) ........

The exact error is:

```
MySuperCoolEntityJpaRepository is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

I do understand the error.  MySuperCoolEntityJpaRepository is abstract.  I get that.

But with this super cool "just extend JpaRepository and get all kinds of default functionality".....

How do I register a concrete JpaRepository with Spring DI (specifically with "code it up" java config ?

............

I tried making it a "class".

```
public class MySuperCoolEntityJpaRepository extends MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract, JpaRepository<MySuperCoolEntity,String>
```

but that wants me to define all those built in methods like "findAll",etc, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround. I don't really like it, but I guess it works.

I also added MySuperCoolEntityBalServiceContract (you can get the idea from just the below), so you know why/how I need to have the getAMySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract method in my CompositionRoot class below.

I'll leave this (not marked) as the answer in case someone else has a better way, or sees issue(s) with the below.  I don't like the EntitiyManager work around, but it got things moving.

```
package com.me.myapplication.configuration;


import com.me.apicore.managers.MySuperCoolEntityBalService;
import com.me.apicore.managers.interfaces.MySuperCoolEntityBalServiceContract;
import com.me.dal.repositories.interfaces.MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@Configuration

public class MyCompositionRoot {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entManager; /* part of the work around trick */

    @Bean
    public MySuperCoolEntityBalServiceContract getAMySuperCoolEntityBalServiceContract() {
        return new MySuperCoolEntityBalService(this.getAMySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract());
    }


    @Bean
    public MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract getAMySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract() {
        //return new MySuperCoolEntityJpaRepository(); /* does not work.  :(         */
        RepositoryFactorySupport factory = new JpaRepositoryFactory(entManager);
        MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract repository = factory.getRepository(MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract.class);
        return repository;
    }
}
```

And I tweaked this (note the addition of the RepositoryDefinition annotation)

```
package com.me.dal.repositories.interfaces;

import com.me.domain.jpaentities.MySuperCoolEntity;

import org.springframework.data.repository.RepositoryDefinition;

import java.util.Collection;

@RepositoryDefinition(domainClass = MySuperCoolEntity.class, idClass = String.class)

public interface MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract {

    Collection<MySuperCoolEntity> findByCoolMagicValue(String coolMagicValue);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot magically provides implementation for the methods defined in  your interface. The `@EnableJpaRepositories` scans all packages below the package for interfaces extending **JpaRepository** and creates a Spring bean for it that is backed by an implementation of **SimpleJpaRepository** (spring data provides default imlpementations of CRUD repository through this class).

Your interface `MySuperCoolEntityJpaRepository`  extends the interface `MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract` , but you only extend the `JpaRepository` on the interface `MySuperCoolEntityJpaRepository` which means spring will only provide the default implementations for methods in the interface `MySuperCoolEntityJpaRepository` . So try it like :

```
public interface MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract extends JpaRepository<MySuperCoolEntity,String>{

    Collection<MySuperCoolEntity> findByCoolMagicValue(String coolMagicValue);

}
```

then extend this in your repository like :

```
@Repository
public interface MySuperCoolEntityJpaRepository extends MySuperCoolEntityRepositoryContract {

    Collection<MySuperCoolEntity> findByCoolMagicValue(String coolMagicValue);

}
```

Related Post : [how annotation @Repository in java spring work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56032969/how-annotation-repository-in-java-spring-work/56033846#56033846)

Comment: This explains the magic of the default methods (findAll, etc) and adding to the JpaRepository methods).  I appreciate the attempt.  But the main point of the is about using java-config to code up the DI, not rely on any scanning.  Future readers can see this link about some of the "freebies" you get with default methods : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts