# Why do we create interface extending other interface instead of using the extended interface directly in Spring Boot Rest Tutorial?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, interface

I am new to Spring Boot. I am following this tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

In this tutorial, there is an interface declaration like this:

```
package payroll;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

First question; Why do we declare this interface? In the code followed during tutorial, if I put JpaRepository<Employee, Long> instead of EmployeeRepository, everything works as before. Why would I use EmployeRepository interface, while original interface is there?

Second question; how is the interface is implemented and created an object of this implementation automatically by Spring Boot? What is the magic behind?

Comment: 1. Because you can add new methods to `EmployeeRepository`. 2. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56032969/3001761.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In your `EmployeeRepository` you could add more methods in addition to the ones already available in `JpaRepository`. You can achieve this simply by adding the methods and Spring will parse their names creating the corresponding query. You can learn more about this at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods. Additionally, `EmployeeRepository` is easier to read and understand than `JpaRepository<Employee, Long>`. this will actually help you and others read your code.
2. You can read more about this also in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods, but the very specific and dirty details can only be found in Spring Framework code itself.

Comment: Also, later you could choose some other framework to implement your Employee repository without having to re-write everything that touched it